# A = (0, 1/2). Find the closure of A in X = (0,1].

Tags: general-topology

$A = (0, 1/2)$. Find the closure of $A$ in $X = (0,1]$.

So $X = (0,1]$ is a topological space with subspace topology $T' = \{ U \bigcap (0,1] \mid U\text{ is open in }\mathbb{R}\}$.

The basis for the subspace topology is $B' = \{ U \bigcap (0,1] \mid U\text{ is open is an open interval}\}$

Obviously $(0,1/2)$ is in the closure of $A$.

I want to use this fact: $x \in \bar{A}$ if and only if for every $B \in B'$, $B \bigcap$ A \neq \phi$

I am guessing that the closure is $[0,1/2]$. However there is no $B$ that contains $0$?

Comment: Note that $[0,1/2] \not \subset X$.  You should have $\bar A = (0,1/2]$.

Answer (score 1):

$1/2$ is a limit point of $A$ (for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ nearer than $\varepsilon$ from $1/2$), and if $x>1/2$ then it is not a limit point of $A$ (choose $\varepsilon:=x-1/2$). So, we have
$$\bar A=(0,\ 1/2]\,.$$